# CompleteBipartite {2,3}

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to explore some graph properties of complete bipartite graphs.  At this point I would be happy to be able to see an unlabeled complete bipartite graph.

I tried:

```
GraphData["CompleteGraph[{2,3}]"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GraphData["CompleteB*"] // Short
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}, "Properties"] // Short
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Select[GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}, "Properties"], 
 GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {2, 3}}, #] == True &]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]